# Making `try_files` redirect instead of serve

Tags: nginx, file-extension

I have a bunch of images (95% JPEG, 4.9% PNG, and 0.1% GIF) which are numbered sequentially, but sometimes have non-uniform extensions (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.png, 4.jpg, ...).

I'd like to be able to request an image *without* specifying the extension and have nginx make the appropriate redirect. I'm currently using `try_files`, but it doesn't redirect:

```
location ~ '^/i/(\d+)/(\d+)$' {
    try_files $1/$2.jpg $1/$2.png $1/$2.gif;
}
```

The nginx docs say that using `if` to check that a file exists is bad, but I don't really know how else I can do it. How do I do something like this?

```
if file has extension:
    serve it and 404 if it doesn't exist
else:
    if   file + .jpg exists, redirect
    elif file + .png exists, redirect
    elif file + .gif exists, redirect

404 if everything else failed
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that with "if file had extension" you mean if the REQUEST_URI ends with one of the image extensions? Cause that's not a special case and not part off the problem.

Comment: @Melvyn: Yes, you're right. I made some progress by manually checking with `if`, but nothing fully functional yet.

Comment: Curious why you want to redirect. Are these really errors in the site and you want to send 301 responses? I mean, why is it not ok to just serve 1.jpg if it exists?

Comment: @Melvyn: I need `cdn.example.com/books/foo/1` to redirect to `cdn.example.com/books/foo/1.jpg`. The file extensions aren't all exactly the same and I need to construct URLs like this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
root /some/path;

if ($uri ~ ^/(books/\d+/\d+)$) {
    set $path $1;
}

if (-f "/some/path/$path.jpg") {
    return 301 "$path.jpg";
}

if (-f "/some/path/$path.png") {
    return 301 "$path.png";
}

if (-f "/some/path/$path.gif") {
    return 301 "$path.gif";
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: As a note for the future, if is evil (see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) - a likely better solution would have been to remove the file extensions from the actual files, as a browser doesn't use them to identify what an image is anyway [but such an answer wouldn't have answered this question]. Either that, or convert all the images so they are all actually the same type.

Comment: @LukeBriggs: Neither is feasible, so `if` is the only solution here.